# English characters don't show up when entering text with Urdu fonts in Swing

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, fonts, paint

This is similar to [my own previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185006/english-characters-dont-show-up-when-entering-text-with-indic-input-method-in-sw), but that solution didn't work here.
As mentioned in the previous question, I'm working on a cross platform(Windows/Ubuntu) application that has to transliterate English into one of several official Indian languages. The application has a custom input method, and typing in English and pressing space will transliterate the typed text into the specific local language. Urdu is different from the others in being right to left, like Arabic/Hebrew.
I managed to find [an open licensed Urdu font](http://www.crulp.org/software/localization/Fonts/nafeesWebNaskh.html) that has both English and Urdu glyphs, but when I type characters in English, nothing shows up.

I don't understand whether it's a font painting issue, or related to the input method. So far, if I disable the custom input method (`InputMethod.dispatchEvent()` ) for this language, I am able to see the English text (but of course no transliteration takes place).

**My findings:**

- Change font to one of Windows' built in Arabic fonts - same result.
- Instead of using `ComponentOrientation` to align text in the text field, I used `setHorizontalAlignment` for when the locale is Urdu. Same result.
- Decompiled the JDK's default input method provider on Windows (`sun.awt.windows.WInputMethod`). Here I see the `dispatchEvent()` makes a native call to the OS for handling IME. I can't do that here.
- Found [a custom IM for Hebrew](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/com/ora/intl/ime/SimpleInputMethod.java.html) - my version of `dispatchEvent()` is essentially the same.
- Stepped through code for `JTextField` in Eclipse - wasn't able to find anything in the `AbstractDocument` and subclasses. The `AbstractDocument.insertUpdate()` method checks for and updates bidirectional text input, but there wasn't anything else significant.

I'm unable to understand what happens after the `dispatchEvent()` call. The characters are being registered, i.e. the transliteration engine is able to detect the typed characters and process them, but they just don't show up on screen.

**Workaround**

If I let the text field's orientation be as it is for regular left to right languages, I can see the English text. However, this would not be acceptable to an Urdu speaking user.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might see if this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010098/jspinner-date-editor-in-buddhist-calendar/2010819#2010819) works with the locale set to Urdu.

Comment: This might be the long shot but for me it seems like [font fallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) problem. The problem is you are working on cross platform application... For Windows you might set [font fallback rule in Registry](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.inst_cr_winux.10.1.0.doc/inst_cr_winux_id21400UpdateFontLinkRegistryEntries.html) (add your font instead Simsun) and see if it works but for Linux this solution won't work :/

Comment: @trashgod - Thanks for the example. I set the locale to ur_IN and component orientation, but now numerals are invisible.

Answer (score 2):

> I set the locale to `ur_IN`.

Sadly, `ur_IN` is not among the [supported locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html); I only see `en_IN` and `hi_IN`. In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010098/jspinner-date-editor-in-buddhist-calendar/2010819#2010819) cited, I used the following code to get the image below:

```
spinner.setLocale(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
```

[image: JSpinnerTest Hindi]

Comment: Sorry, this isn't an answer, but I thought information might be apropos.

Comment: Thanks. I've found that Urdu is recognized as a right to left language. By using a JTextPane instead, and some tweaks to the custom input method (cursor positioning etc), we're able to get the correct behavior now.