# Fonts do not display correctly - Java

Tags: java, fonts, awt

I have some words in English that have been translated into Tamil. The task requires me to display them. An example line is given below. The first and second lines are in Tamil while the last is in Bengali.

```
> unpopular ஜனங்கலால் வெறுக்கப்பட்ட             ¤µ£»ªÀ»õu 
inactive    ஜடமான           ö\¯»ØÓ
doctor  வைத்தியர்           ©¸zxÁº
apart   வேறாக           uÂµ
```

If you notice above, the text in some lines does not render correctly because it is written in custom fonts. The custom font can be downloaded from [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/0jliQ7X5/WTAM001.html). My problem:
1. All Tamil fonts (custom and pre-loaded) have been installed. None of the text displays correctly. Why?
2. Is there a problem with the way that I am loading custom fonts?
3. In the above lines, the second column is pre-loaded font while the third column is written in custom fonts. The third column does not seem like it is Unicode, which is why application of any font also fails. What is going on?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/* This is the imageMaker class.
 * It loads a plain white image, writes text taken from another file
 * and creates a new image from it.
 * 
 * Steps: 
 * 1. A plain white image is loaded.
 * 2. Text is taken from a file.
 * 3. Text is written to the image.
 * 4. New image is created and saved.
 */

public class imgMaker_so {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    private static String tgtDir = "YOUR_tgt directory to store images goes here";
    private static String csvFile = "csv file goes here";
    private static int fontSize = 22;  //default to a 22 pt font.

    private static Font f;
    private static String fontName = "WTAM001"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Step 0. Read the image.
        //readPlainImage(plainImg);

        //Step 0.a: Check if the directory exists. If not, create it.
        File tgtDir_file = new File(tgtDir);
        if(!tgtDir_file.exists()) { //this directory does not exist.
            tgtDir_file.mkdir();
        }

        Font nf = null;
        try {
            nf = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\" + fontName + ".ttf"));
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(nf != null) {
            f = nf.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, fontSize);
        }

        if(f == null) {
            System.out.println("Font is still null.");
        }

        //Step 1. Read csv file and get the string.
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(csvFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String temp = "\u0b85";
        System.out.println(temp.length());
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(temp.charAt(i));
        }

        //SAMPLE CODE ONLY. CHECK IF IT CAN PRINT A SINGLE CHARACTER IN FONT.
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(410, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 410, 200);

        System.out.println("String being printed = " + temp.codePointAt(0));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setFont(f);
        if(f.canDisplay('\u0b85')) {
            System.out.println("Can display code = \u0b85");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot display code = \u0b85");
        }
        g.drawString(temp, 10, 35);         

        //g.drawString(translation, 10, fontWidth); //a 22pt font is approx. 35 pixels long.
        g.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File(tgtDir + "\\" + "a.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("File written successfully to a");

        //System.out.println("Cat,,बिल्ली,,,");

        if(fis != null) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
                System.out.print("Unsupported encoding");
            }

            String line = null;
            if(br != null) {
                try {
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        if(line != null) {
                            System.out.println("Line = " + line);
                            List<String> word_translation = new ArrayList<String>();
                            parseLine(line, word_translation);  //function to parse the line.
                            //printImages(word_translation);
                            if(word_translation.size() > 0) {
                                printImages_temp(word_translation);
                            }
                            //now that images have been read, read the plain image afresh.
                            //readPlainImage(plainImg);
                            word_translation.clear();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printImages_temp(List<String> list) {

        /* Function to print translations contained in list to images.
         * Steps:
         * 1. Take plain white image.
         * 2. Write English word on top.
         * 3. Take each translation and print one to each line.
         */

        String dest = tgtDir + "\\" + list.get(0) + ".jpg";  //destination file image.

        //compute height and width of image.
        int img_height = list.size() * 35 + 20;
        int img_width = 0;
        int max_length = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(list.get(i).length() > max_length) {
                max_length = list.get(i).length();
            }
        }
        img_width = max_length * 20;

        System.out.println("New dimensions of image = " + img_width + " " + img_height);

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(img_width, img_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, img_width, img_height);

        //image has to be written to another file. Do not write English word, which is why list starts iteration from 1.
        for(int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("String being printed = " + list.get(i).codePointAt(0));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(f);
            g.drawString(list.get(i), 10, (i + 1) * 35);            
        }

        //g.drawString(translation, 10, fontWidth); //a 22pt font is approx. 35 pixels long.
        g.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", new File(dest));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("File written successfully to " + dest);
    }

    public static void purge(String line) {
        //This removes any inverted commas and tabs from the line apart from trimming it.
        System.out.println("Line for purging = " + line);
        int fromIndex = line.indexOf("\"");
        //System.out.println("from index = " + fromIndex);
        if(fromIndex != -1) {
            line = line.substring((fromIndex + 1));
            int toIndex = line.lastIndexOf("\"", line.length() - 1);
            if(toIndex != -1) {
                line = line.substring(0, (toIndex));
            }
        }
        line.replaceAll("\t", " ");
        line.trim();
        System.out.println("Line after purging = " + line);
    }

    public static void parseLine(String line, List<String> result) {

        /* 
         * This function parses the string and gets the different hindi meanings.
         */

        //int index = line.indexOf(",");
        //int prev_index = 0;

        String[] arr = line.split(",");
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));

        for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            if(l.get(i).isEmpty()) {  //if the string at position i is empty.
                l.remove(i);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {  //inefficient copy but should be short.
            String ith = l.get(i).trim();
            if(!(ith.isEmpty())) {   //add a string to result only if it is non-empty.
                //in some entries, there are commas. they have been replaced with !?. find them and replace them.
                if(ith.contains("!?")) {
                    //System.out.println(r + " contains !?");
                    String r = ith.replace("!?", ",");
                    result.add(r);
                } else if(ith.contains("\n")) {
                    String r = ith.replace("\n", " ");
                    System.out.println("found new line in " + ith);
                    result.add(r);
                } else {
                    result.add(ith);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Result[" + i + "] = " + result.get(i));
        }

        //System.out.println("Line being printed = " + line);
    }
}
```

The above text was written by professional translators. So, is there something here that I am missing?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hotlink to a suitable `Font` if possible (by `URL`).

Comment: @Andrew: An SSCCE... does that help?

Answer (score 1):

- to test the concrete Font with methods in API [Font.canDisplay](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29)
- required to test in [Unicode form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (for mixing chars from a few  languages (Tamil & Bengali))
- please can you post and SSCCE, with used Font and [can be based on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318215/714968)

Comment: I have added an SSCCE. Please take a look.